# Zapier New Platform UI - Handle z.request() method in map()

Tags: javascript, node.js, zapier

Since I tried return file using z.dehydrate() method in many ways. It didn't works for me. And then I implemented below code.

```
return z.request(options)
  .then((response) => {
  response.throwForStatus();
    const results = z.JSON.parse(response.content);
    let promises = [];
    let attachmentArray = results.data.map(function(result){
      let attachment = {};
      attachment.id = result.attachment_id;
      let file_url = options.url + `/${attachment.id}`;
      attachment.url = file_url;
      z.request({
        url: attachmentUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${bundle.authData.access_token}`},
        raw: true
      }).then((fileContent)=>{
        attachment.file = fileContent;
      });
      return attachment;
    });
    return attachmentArray;
  });
```

It successfully populates the JSONArray. File streamed content successfully fetched in HTTP logs. But, the attachment.file value not fetching because, its asynchronous. I used async/await, it throws error in New Zapier UI code mode. How can I achieve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error does using `async` throw?

Comment: I am using New Zapier platform. Since it has Code Switch mode. In the code editor it shows some ; error. Then I straight away save and tested. It throws error like async is need to use await. @xavdid